# Lemma without numbering

Tags: formatting, numbering, theorems, ieeetran

I want to use the lemma environment without numbering because I only have one lemma. If I use the package `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}` I get "Lemma 1" in Italics and indented:

```
\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
this is my lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

And if I do

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
```

I get "Lemma" but in bold and plain font. I want the Italics, indentation, but without the number. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

[image]

Since the class used is `IEEEtran`, the `amsthm` approach I initially suggested is not the best option (`IEEEtran` handles theorem-like environments in its own way). In this case, since the class doesn't make provision for unnumbered structures, you can achieve the desired unnumbered structure in a consistent way simply redefining the associated counter to `\unskip`:

The code:

```
\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\renewcommand\thelemma{\unskip}
\begin{document}
Test text
\begin{lemma}
this is my lemma
\end{lemma}
Test text
\end{document}
```

### Initial version (for a standard class)

If I understood your request correctly, you can use the `remark` style from `amsthm`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Test lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: with this the "Lemma" is no longer indented.

Comment: @Elnaz What do you mean by "indented"? It is never indented, by default. Please clarify.

Comment: When I only use `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}`, the "Lemma" keyword appears indented. But with your code above it sits exactly below the normal text above it with no indentation.

Comment: @Elnaz No; that is not the default behaviour. Please provide a simple document, like the one in my answer illustrating the indentation you mention.

Comment: I'll edit my original post with the code.

Comment: How do I show you the result?

Comment: @Elnaz please see my updated answer.